# Is it possible to make actor variables

Tags: python

Sorry to waste time, but I was just wondering if you could put pygame zero Actors into variables, and when you use a variable, it could place all of the actors at once?

Comment: It is better to make them a class

Comment: What is a class? (lol I'm noob)

Comment: Welcom to SO! Your questions should be much more elaborate and ideally include code examples of what you tried. StackOverflow isn't the place to let others teach you how to code, it can only help you solve very specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do so as long as you are using a return and defining the variable before using return, however you may edit it and use it after the return function